# Can I clone windows 7 with standart widows 7 tools?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, clone

I tried xcopy c:\ f:\ /s /e /h /i /c /y in cmd to no avail.
I set up new ssd as boot1 priority, to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

I read that somehow I need to copy reserved by the system 100 mb particion. How do I do that? And wouldnt it be conflicting with old system while im trying to boot?

Maybe it will work if I just disconnect source ssd now, because it is conflicting already?

How can I fix it without messing with my pc insides? It is really hard to reach those ssds.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can do this with standard Windows tools. To clone a Windows 7 system means bringing everything (partition information, files, Registry and so on). Xcopy does not clone the registry.

There a number of tools for this. We use Ghost at our clients, make the image on a USB hard drive and then restore it when we need it. Acronis can do this as well.

But so far as I know, you need a third party tool to clone the system